# Are questions about game connection problems on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Are questions regarding difficulty connecting to a specific game on topic? I believe I've seen some questions that are often down voted regarding difficulty connecting to some game, but usually they are questions that lack details as to what is happening, or things the user has tried.

Comment: What do you mean 'connecting to a specific game'? Do you mean network issues? Connecting you account? Integrating content from one game in another?

Comment: Network issues yes, regarding the game 7 days to Die on Xbox one. My friends and I are having trouble connecting to one another.

Comment: imo, yes it should be on topic, but that being said it's likely to be one of those 'guess' answers, people will guess as to the cause and guess a possible solution in the answers or the comments. If the OP of these sorts of questions does not interact with the people trying to help then I think it should be closed as too broad

Comment: Also network connection problems are often caused by not having port forwarded

Comment: So asking a question about why my friend and I are having trouble connecting to the game would be too broad (even after listing everything we have tried)?  I have tried port forwarding, but I'm not 100% on if I did it correctly.

Comment: It will be too broad if you don't give enough detail.  As long as you detail clearly what you have tried, and respond to comments, the question should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are questions regarding difficulty connecting to a specific game on topic?

Yes, **[Game-specific hardware and utilities](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**
 are on-topic.

> I believe I've seen some questions that are often down voted regarding difficulty connecting to some game, but usually they are questions that lack details as to what is happening, or things the user has tried.

Downvoting should not be confused with off-topic.  Voting is for users to decide if they like a question.  Reasons for liking or not liking a question is just an indicator for good/bad questions.  If people find the question well structured and useful it is more likely to be up-voted.  If it contains no effort, such as content and spelling then you are likely to see down votes.

If you want your question to be on-topic just make sure it fits in with the guidance on the help centre (see link at the top).  Clearly detail the problem and you should be fine.

Some examples of network issue questions:

- [Why isn't my Minecraft LAN server working?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79252/why-isnt-my-minecraft-lan-server-working)
- ["Unable to connect to public sessions. Please check your NAT type" error when playing online?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170029/unable-to-connect-to-public-sessions-please-check-your-nat-type-error-when-pl)
- [Multiple Xbox Ones on same network attempting to play public black ops 3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/243220/multiple-xbox-ones-on-same-network-attempting-to-play-public-black-ops-3)

Comment: Thanks for providing some examples and the answer!